# Can't change session value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

I use the session in codeigniter, it works well but I can't change the value.
I use this function :

```
$this->session->set_userdata('check', 0);
```

I must change the value of 'check' to 0.

Why can't ?

My question is, why i can't change the value session ?  And I set the value like this for the first time :

```
$sess_array = array(
        'userid' => $row->userid,
        'pseudo' => $row->pseudo,
        'check'  => $row->check
);  
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
```

Comment: Whats the question it seems unclear

Comment: how did you set the value in the first time??

Comment: That code must change session value.How you know it does not work?

Comment: Did you load your session library? like this : `$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: @Maraboc : I load session in the autoload.php  (@)Shaiful Islam : I do a print_r on session variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sess_array = array(
    'userid' => $row->userid,
    'pseudo' => $row->pseudo,
    'check'  => $row->check
); 
// you have set session key 'logged_in' 
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);

// Get session value from existing key
$arrSession = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$arrSession['check'] = 0;
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $arrSession);
```

You need to update value as shown above.

If you wish to set 'check' value as you indicated. you need to do as following

```
$sess_array = array(
    'userid' => $row->userid,
    'pseudo' => $row->pseudo,
    'check'  => $row->check
); 
// Note that no key specified. 
$this->session->set_userdata($sess_array);
// Now i think you can set check value. Give it a try. Let me know which works.
$this->session->set_userdata('check',0);
```

Comment: @jorisreix Gr8. Happy it helps you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try unsetting the value and then assign a new value to it, Something like the below code:

```
$check= $this->session->userdata('check');

if(!empty($check)){
  $this->session->unset_userdata('check');
  $this->session->set_userdata('check', 0);
}
echo $this->session->userdata('check');
```

Let me know if that works!!